# (subsonic) problem with deleting rows (my table contains Deleted column)

Tags: subsonic

I have a table named 'Test' contains

- id int
- name nvarchar
- Deleted bit

columns.

First i install subsonic in my project using sql server 2000.
where i try to delete some rows, it throw object null exception for me on line:

```
repo.Update(); //object reference not set to...
```

---

I config subsonic again with sql server 2008,
Now when i try to delete row, it work fine! even when i change connection string to sql 2000.

But my current problem is:

When i try to delete some rows that does not exists with lambda expression like below it threw a new exception:

```
Test.Delete(a=>a.id==100); //it doesn't exists!
//...
repo.Update();
//ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized
```

I use VS2008, sql2008 & sql2000 and subsonic 3.0.0.4

Comment: are you using `ActiveRecord` for `Test` class?

Comment: A full stack trace would help, I lost my crystal ball :D

Comment: yes, i create classes by active record t4.